# I broke access logging for Apache Virtual Host. So weird - help

Tags: logs, apache-virtualhost

I had an access log that I wanted to save and then clear the original one. I renamed the access.log and then created a new access.log with the same permissions.

No logging. I restarted Apache2 a couple of times and nothing being added to the access.log file. The error.log file in the same folder keeps growing.

Also the logging in other virtual hosts is fine.

So now I read that your not supposed to touch the log files while Apache2 is running. I broke thier rule now it's punishing me.

The virtual host configuration is unchanged. Is there a place in the Apache config that it turned logging off for that virtual host?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fixed after I rebooted the entire server. Restarting Apache didn't fix it.

I had another problem that started at the same time....on SFTP uploads a file of 0 size would be created and then the file transfer would fail. The server reboot fixed this issue also.

So unexplainable. Similar to like how did he get to be POTUS :(